# Is there anyway to return a "no searches found" with this javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is a function called and returns matches from a json file. Is there anyway to return a no matches found?

```
function displayMatches() {
  const searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value;
  const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, name);

  const html = matchArray.map(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(searchText);
    const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${searchText}</span>`);

    return `
        <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank">
            <li>
                <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)}</span> 
                <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100">
            </li>
        </a>
    `;
  }).join('');
  suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.map` will return an empty array if there's nothing found, so you can alternate the `.join('')` with a different string:

```
}).join('') || 'No searches found';
```

Or do it when assigning the new HTML

```
suggestions.innerHTML = html || 'No searches found';
```

Comment: An empty array will be truthy, so you'll always short circuit.

Comment: The `.join('')`ed empty array will be falsey.

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt to do something like this:

```js
...
const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, name);

let html;

if (matchArray.length === 0) {
 html = 'No matches found'; // or some HTML equivalent
} else {
 // your mapping from above
}

suggestions.innerHTML = html;
...
```